# Accessing an inner subclass with private class constructor from another class

Tags: java, android, class, private

I'm creating SQL Database and i base on [this site.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow)
The problem is, i don't know how can i access inner class' methods, while outer class has private constructor.

```
public class MyDBHandler {

    private MyDBHandler() {
    }

    public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tasks";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "TASK_LABEL";
    }

    public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";

        public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public long saveTasks(String title) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);

            long newRowId = db.insert(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            return newRowId;

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access saveTasks(String title) method from onClick(View v) method from an another java file.

I tried sth like this:

```
MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper dbHelper = new MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper(v.getContext());
```

but of course i get an "MyDBHandler is not an enclosing class" error.

OR

```
MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper dbHelper= new MyDBHandler().new FeedReaderDbHelper(v.getContext());
```

but again, Android studio keeps telling me: "MyDbHandler has a private access"

Is it even possible to do it that way?

Comment: Move your FeedReaderDbHelper class into separate file

Comment: Why exactly are you implementing it as an inner class? In the example it's clearly a separate class.

Comment: why can't you make the constructor public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyDbHandler has a private access
```

This is not about the inner class, it is about the constructor in that class

```
private MyDBHandler() {
}
```

I guess I saw this guide (website) before and I didn't really know why they added it as an inner class. I remember they said to make the constructor private so no one can create an object out of it.
So simply move the `FeedReaderDbHelper` to a separate file and then it will work.

But if for some reason you want to keep it inner class then define it as static

```
public static class FeedReaderDbHelper
```

Then call the same code and it should work

Comment: The problem is, when I move FeedReaderDbHelper to separate file, it just doesn't have access to variables, like SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES. I would have to create getters to solve it. Would it be an optimal solution?

Comment: ofcourse it has access they are decalered public static so you can access them like this CLASS_NAME.STATIC_PUBLIC_VARS, otherwise getters only will be optimal one yes

Comment: yeah, I was just trying to stick as much as it is only possible to this android dev's guide, where vars are private. Anyway, I'll just use getters.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to keep your inner class then make it static and use it as follow:

`new MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext())`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the inner class static to use it

```
public class MyDBHandler {

private MyDBHandler() {
}

public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tasks";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "TASK_LABEL";
}

public static class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public long saveTasks(String title) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);

        long newRowId = db.insert(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return newRowId;

    }
  }
}
```

Now to get an instance of FeedReaderDbHelper you can

```
MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper dbHelper = new MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper(v.getContext());
```

and to call methods

```
String title = "your title";
dbHelper.saveTasks(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner class is just a way to cleanly separate some functionality that really belongs to the original outer class. They are intended to be used when you have 2 requirements:

1. Some piece of functionality in your outer class would be most clear
   if it was implemented in a separate class.
2. Even though it's in a separate class, the functionality is very closely tied 
   to way that the outer class works.

Given these requirements, inner classes have full access to their outer class. Since they're basically a member of the outer class, it makes sense that they have access to methods and attributes of the outer class -- including privates

followings are the way:

```
new MyDBHandler.FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext())
```

**`I have run your code by following way, Please have a look.`**

```
public class MyDBHandler {

        public static FeedReaderDbHelper feedReaderDbHelper;
        private MyDBHandler() {
        }

        public static FeedReaderDbHelper getFeedReaderDbHelper()
        {
            if(feedReaderDbHelper == null)
                feedReaderDbHelper = new MyDBHandler(). new FeedReaderDbHelper();

            return feedReaderDbHelper;
        }
        public static class FeedEntry  {
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tasks";
            public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "TASK_LABEL";
        }

        public class FeedReaderDbHelper  {
            public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";

            public FeedReaderDbHelper() {
                //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            public long saveTasks(String title) {
                System.out.println(title);

                return 1L;
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyDBHandler.getFeedReaderDbHelper().saveTasks("title");
        }
    }
```